# Using SQL CASE Statement to replace Text with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am Using SQL Server and i have the following Problem and i am hopping someone could help me.

I am getting this Error

```
    Column 'TransactionsLine.Text' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

I do not want to include Text in the GROUP BY Clause yes that makes the query run but the issue is there is other text in the field i do not want it grouping by i would just like to replace the Name with the Text for items matching the CASE

when i add Text to the group by i get this result.

```
           43036    SPECIAL     73.0000
           43036    SPECIAL     6.0000
```

Comment: I don't know if this is what you actually want, but repeat the CASE in GROUP BY instead of `StockItems.Description`

Comment: Why is this tagged with `mysql`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is exactly what the error says. You are selecting `TransactionsLine.text` which is not in the group by clause.

you probably want to put the case in your `group by` clause:

```
select StockItemCode as CODE,
    (
        case 
            when StockItems.Description like 'item%'
                then TransactionsLine.text
            else StockItems.Description
            end
        ) as name,
    SUM(ItemQuantity) as Sales
from Transactions
inner join TransactionsLine on Transactions.id = TransactionsLine.TransactionID
inner join StockItems on TransactionsLine.StockItemID = StockItems.id
where location = @location
    and Department = 43
    and Transactions.date between @FROM
        and @TO
    and TransactionTypeID in (3, 32)
group by StockItemCode,
    case 
        when StockItems.Description like 'item%'
            then TransactionsLine.text
        else StockItems.Description
        end
```